# Buscar mês inteiro ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, data

Preciso executar um relatório que me devolva os valores do todo o mês anterior.
Utilizava o seguinte forma:

```
where cliente.dtultcomp > trunc (SYSDATE-30)
```

Porem existe casos do mês ter 28, 31 dias por exemplo.
Existe uma forma de sempre me trazer o mês anterior completo independente da quantidade de dias no mês ou dia de execução?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma opção mais simples seria utilizar a função add_mouths, que passando um valor negativo subtrai meses da data, ex:

```
...    
where cliente.dtultcomp > add_months(sysdate, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso você poderia usar no WHERE para:
1. Comparar o mês atual - 1 com o mês da data
2. Comparar o ano atual com o ano da data

Isso é fácil usando a função [`EXTRACT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm):

O problema é no caso do mês 1, que se subtraído daria 0 e o ano deveria ser subtraído também. Para esse caso, uma lógica simples usando `CASE WHEN`:

```
where (case when EXTRACT(month from sysdate) = 1
           then 12
           else EXTRACT(month from sysdate)-1 end) = EXTRACT(month from cliente.dtultcomp)
  and  (case when EXTRACT(month from sysdate) = 1
           then EXTRACT(year from sysdate)-1
           else EXTRACT(year from sysdate) end) = EXTRACT(year from cliente.dtultcomp)
```

Com isso, vai resolver isso: *"devolva os valores do todo o mês anterior"*

Um exemplo no *SQL fiddle*: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db477/1